# Which Azure role / permission needed for command using Azure function

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, azure-ad-graph-api

I've created a solution that will auto-tag all resources in Azure when they're created using the "Creator", "Date", and "Time." These work perfectly if someone creates from the web interface. Unfortunately, I use Terraform to create resources and would like it to take the terraform appid and convert it to the name using the following command.

```
(Get-AzADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId "123456-4564-464651651").DisplayName
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error, basically saying i don't have privileges to do it. Is there a list that lets me know which roles correspond to which command i need to run? I only want to allow privileges to map Service Principle App ID display name (and nothing more).

```
[Error] ERROR: [Authorization_RequestDenied] : Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.Exception             :Type    : System.ExceptionMessage : [Authorization_RequestDenied] : Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.HResult : -2146233088CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: ({ ConsistencyLevel …ect = , Expand =  }:<>f__AnonymousType5`7) [Get-AzADServicePrincipal_List], ExceptionFullyQualifiedErrorId
```

The solution is based on this link using Event triggers https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/core-infrastructure-and-security/tagging-azure-resources-with-a-creator/ba-p/1479819

Answer (score 0):

You should you at least Application.Read.All permission , Please see the doc for more info - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

[image]

Hope this helps

Thanks